# datarow values comparision with c#

Tags: c#

I have a sql database with a table that contains my grading scales and comment e.g

```
debut        end        comment  
5  ----       10   --      x  
0  ----        4   ---     y
```

I have managed to iterate through the rows of my table with a foreach loop.

I want to supply a value, maybe with a text box control, then the program should check the range in my `gradingScale` table where the value follows and outputs a corresponding comment

for example

```
int number;
number=4

comment=y;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? And please explain which column you want to range on. And how you are trying to display it...

Comment: @Martin Does the input value need to satisfy any range criteria ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for - and you didn't mention **what** database you're using - so here I'm just guess that you might be looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @Number INT
SET @Number = 4

SELECT comment
FROM dbo.gradingScale
WHERE @Number BETWEEN debut AND end
```

Of course, you could also wrap this inside a stored procedure (if your database supports that):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetComment (@Number INT)
AS
   SELECT comment
   FROM dbo.gradingScale
   WHERE @Number BETWEEN debut AND end
```

These code samples are for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and up (T-SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to make out what you want exactly, but here's an example implementation (You don't say how or in what form your Sql results are returned, so I've provided a DTO/List implementation:

```
static void SO6648999()
{
    List<test> sample = new List<test> 
        {
        new test {  debut = 0,
                    end = 4,
                    comment = "y"},
        new test {  debut = 5,
                    end = 10,
                    comment = "x"}
        };
    int number = 4;
    string comment = sample.Single(x => number >= x.debut && number <= x.end).comment;
}

class test
{
    public int debut;
    public int end;
    public string comment;
}
```

Comment: Sorting the list by (start, end) would allow for a logarithmic complexity here =)

Comment: Based on the complexity and general state of the OP (or lack thereof) I opted for a simple to read case.  I hoped the simple _between_ lambda to be easy to read - adding orders might make it less obvious.  Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your database list ranges, each associated with a comment. In your example 0 to 4 map to x, while 5 to 10 map to y.

In that case, a very simple approach would be, assuming that your ranges are not overlapping, to sort your table by ascending `debut`, and then iterate over the rows until you find one which start is `<=` to your value.

Comment: Of course, if you're ready to drop your DB here (sounds like overkill to me but well) you can use a binary search for an efficient implementation.

Comment: where did `start` come from ?

Answer (score -2):

I believe you are referring to `DataTable`

You can use a Select on the `DataTable` and filter out the records by providing an expression. It works similar to a where clause in Sql.

```
dt1.Select("end = 4")// assuming column holding int value
```

end is the column name of the value you are searching and this will return the `datarow` (array) satisfying the condition.

Comment: It seems to me that the input need not appear in the table, based on the op question.

Comment: That is, the op is not searching for a value in the end column, but instead searching for which range the number falls into. Eg. 0->4 poor, 4->6 average, 6->8 good, 8->10 excellent.

Comment: Well there are n cases then which value is to be considered if the exact value is not in the table, just suggesting an approach to get it. The OP hasn't stated that it might not occur in the table at all

Comment: @Clement He hasn't explicitly stated an example for the same.(you downvoted based on your assumption of what the OP wants :))

Comment: `then the program should check the range in my gradingScale table where the value follows and outputs a corresponding comment` -> I think `follows` should be understood as `falls`.

Comment: Fair one - definitely one of those posts you need a crystal ball for. Most have made the assumption that this was a _between_ because that seemed the logical conclusion to the OP@s rambles.  Quite common to spot and make these assumptions - if we were all nit picky we wouldn't be able to answer half the questions on SO ^^